# Fetching data from Json and displaying it in Combobox

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I am trying to get a json file using a url and deserialize the json and display a particular field in the combobox but nothing shows up

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string json = 
client.DownloadString("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/");
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
{
DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new 
DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
RootObject obj = (RootObject)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
foreach (var name in obj.name)
{
comboBox1.Items.Add(obj.name);
}
}
```

this is the POCO class

```
public class RootObject
{
public string name { get; set; }
public List<string> topLevelDomain { get; set; }
public string alpha2Code { get; set; }
public string alpha3Code { get; set; }
public List<string> callingCodes { get; set; }
public string capital { get; set; }
public List<object> altSpellings { get; set; }
public string region { get; set; }
public string subregion { get; set; }
public int population { get; set; }
public List<object> latlng { get; set; }
public string demonym { get; set; }
public double? area { get; set; }
public double? gini { get; set; }
public List<string> timezones { get; set; }
public List<object> borders { get; set; }
public string nativeName { get; set; }
public string numericCode { get; set; }
public List<Currency> currencies { get; set; }
public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
public Translations translations { get; set; }
public string flag { get; set; }
public List<object> regionalBlocs { get; set; }
public string cioc { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display the name in the combobox

here is the link to the json
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add manage nuget package :  **Newtonsoft.Json**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string json =
client.DownloadString("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/");
dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryName>>(json);
foreach (var item in dyn)
{
  comboBox1.Items.Add(item.name);
}

public class CountryName
{
  public string name { get; set; }    
}
```

Best and fast approach and it's working fine

Comment: I too used Newtonsoft.Json and tried first i used a url which has details about a single entry it worked fined but later i tried on a json with multiple entries but it didn't worked. If i am not annoying you, can i send u the code. so, u could be able to spot out the mistakes i made. so, i could able to correct it

Comment: @Dinesh above code is work because you get a response with single JSON object when you get a JSON response with the array you must need to DeserializeObject with a list of item.

Answer (score 1):

You was trying deserialized one result, however result are list.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string json = 
client.DownloadString("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/");
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
{
DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new 
DataContractJsonSerializer(List<RootObject>); //TODO: FIXED
List<RootObject>obj = (List<RootObject>)deserializer.ReadObject(ms); //TODO: FIXED
foreach (var name in obj.name)
{
comboBox1.Items.Add(obj.name);
}
}
```

it´s work

Answer (score 0):

@A.M.Patel
i couldn't able to post it in the comment section
the code u sent worked perfectly
i too used newtonsoft.json
if iam not annoying you
can u spot out my mistakes in my code

1st code which i tried for single entry

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
string url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/ind";
HttpResponseMessage response = http.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;
string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
var details = JObject.Parse(countries.ToString());
comboBox1.Items.Add(countrynames);
```

it worked well

2nd code which i tried for multiple entries it doesn't showed any values in the combobox the combobox remained empty

```
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
IDictionary<String, Int32> countrycounts = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
string url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/";
HttpResponseMessage response = http.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;
string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
var details = JObject.Parse(countries.ToString());
foreach (var obj in details){
string countrynames = details["name"].ToString();
if (countrycounts.ContainsKey(countrynames))
{
int count = countrycounts[countrynames];
count++;
countrycounts[countrynames] = count;
comboBox1.Items.Add(countrynames);
}
else { comboBox1.Items.Add(countrynames); }
```